# USB ports not working after booting Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu

I've had Xubuntu 14.04 for a couple or years, dual boot with Win7, on a HP430G notebook. In the last year or so I'm getting this problem, more and more often.

I use a USB hub with optical mouse and keyboard. When I turn the computer on, I see the light under the mouse, which shows that its USB port is powered. The light stays on during BIOS startup and up to the Grub selection panel. I select Ubuntu with the external keyboard, which works well, Xubuntu starts booting on a black screen and there's still power on the USB port, then when the Xubuntu blue splash screen appears, still loading the system, the light disappears and USB ports are all dead. No power, no recognition of external devices, nothing. I have to reboot (using the internal touchpad) and the second time USB ports normally work, but sometimes I have to reboot 2-3 times.

This used to happen every 3-4 times I turned the computer on, now it's getting worse and occurring virtually every time. Never happens with Windows. It occurs when something is plugged into the USB ports and when it isn't, with or without the USB hub, with or without battery.

Someone asked a similar question here, but no answer yet:

[USB ports not responding at times in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS at startup but works after a reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767639/usb-ports-not-responding-at-times-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-at-startup-but-works-after).

**UPDATE**

I tried to look at the output of 
dmesg | grep usb
after a session with problems and after one that went smoothly. In both cases I had a USB hub in one of the ports, containing optical mouse, keyboard and printer (the latter turned off).

Here's the output.

SESSIONS WITH PROBLEMS

me@me-HP430:~$ dmesg | grep usb
[    1.987749] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.987760] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.987784] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    2.620031] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.620033] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.620036] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.620038] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-86-generic ehci_hcd
[    2.620039] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    2.621637] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.621639] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.621641] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.621643] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-86-generic xhci_hcd
[    2.621645] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    2.622438] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    2.622440] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.622442] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.622444] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-86-generic xhci_hcd
[    2.622446] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    2.931880] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    3.064215] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    3.064220] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.231713] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    3.249278] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608
[    3.249283] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    3.249286] usb 2-2: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    3.363630] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    3.380997] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=311f
[    3.381003] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.547527] usb 2-5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    3.564908] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=138a, idProduct=003f
[    3.564912] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[    3.564915] usb 2-5: SerialNumber: 00b014468492
[    3.731375] usb 2-7: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.786766] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b3c8
[    3.786771] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    3.786774] usb 2-7: Product: HP HD Webcam
[    3.786776] usb 2-7: Manufacturer: Generic
[    3.786777] usb 2-7: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[    3.859348] usb 2-2.2: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    3.879824] usb 2-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510
[    3.879829] usb 2-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.879832] usb 2-2.2: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    3.879834] usb 2-2.2: Manufacturer: PixArt
[    3.879995] usb 2-2.2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    3.951254] usb 2-2.3: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    3.988132] usb 2-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=1702
[    3.988137] usb 2-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.988140] usb 2-2.3: Product: USB Keyboard
[    3.988142] usb 2-2.3: Manufacturer:
[    3.988302] usb 2-2.3: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    3.988309] usb 2-2.3: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[   16.262093] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   16.897338] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   16.897341] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   17.032417] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   17.032418] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   17.036005] input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/input/input14
[   17.036202] hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.2/input0
[   17.036385] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.0/input/input15
[   17.036542] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.3/input0
[   17.039704] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.1/input/input16
[   17.039901] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.3/input1
[   17.167903] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[   17.169184] input: HP HD Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/input/input17
[   17.169282] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   22.165180] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 0 at /build/linux-A0LYlV/linux-3.13.0/drivers/usb/host/xhci-ring.c:1590 handle_cmd_completion+0xe56/0xe60()
[   22.165182] Modules linked in: bnep rfcomm snd_hda_codec_hdmi binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_idt uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops hid_generic videobuf2_core videodev usbhid hid hp_wmi sparse_keymap rtsx_pci_ms arc4 ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath memstick mac80211 intel_rapl ath3k x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp cfg80211 coretemp btusb bluetooth kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper mei_me cryptd joydev hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev mei snd_hda_intel i915 snd_hda_codec wmi lpc_ich snd_hwdep snd_pcm drm_kms_helper drm hp_wireless shpchp i2c_algo_bit video snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid serio_raw parport_pc ppdev lp parport rtsx_pci_sdmmc psmouse ahci libahci r8169 mii rtsx_pci
[   27.570177] usb 2-4: device not accepting address 8, error -108
[   42.559076] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   42.559080] usb 2-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[   42.615325] usb 2-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 7
[   42.727239] usb 2-5: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   42.727468] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 5
me@me-HP430:~$

**SESSION WITHOUT PROBLEMS**

me@me-HP430:~$ dmesg | grep usb
[    1.987766] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.987776] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.987800] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    2.620048] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.620050] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.620052] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    2.620054] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-86-generic ehci_hcd
[    2.620056] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    2.621653] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.621655] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.621657] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.621659] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-86-generic xhci_hcd
[    2.621661] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    2.622453] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    2.622455] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.622457] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.622459] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-86-generic xhci_hcd
[    2.622461] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    2.931903] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    3.064234] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    3.064239] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.235723] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    3.253286] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608
[    3.253291] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    3.253294] usb 2-2: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    3.367608] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    3.385137] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=311f
[    3.385142] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.551500] usb 2-5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    3.568922] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=138a, idProduct=003f
[    3.568927] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[    3.568931] usb 2-5: SerialNumber: 00b014468492
[    3.735433] usb 2-7: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    3.790751] usb 2-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b3c8
[    3.790756] usb 2-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    3.790758] usb 2-7: Product: HP HD Webcam
[    3.790760] usb 2-7: Manufacturer: Generic
[    3.790762] usb 2-7: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[    3.863364] usb 2-2.2: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[    3.883692] usb 2-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510
[    3.883697] usb 2-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.883699] usb 2-2.2: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    3.883701] usb 2-2.2: Manufacturer: PixArt
[    3.883864] usb 2-2.2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    3.891888] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.891891] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.893732] input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.2/2-2.2:1.0/input/input12
[    3.893896] hid-generic 0003:093A:2510.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.2/input0
[    3.955288] usb 2-2.3: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[    3.995756] usb 2-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=1702
[    3.995761] usb 2-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    3.995763] usb 2-2.3: Product: USB Keyboard
[    3.995765] usb 2-2.3: Manufacturer:
[    3.995920] usb 2-2.3: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    3.995925] usb 2-2.3: ep 0x82 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    4.006753] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.0/input/input13
[    4.006850] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.3/input0
[    4.023979] input:   USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.1/input/input14
[    4.024687] hid-generic 0003:04D9:1702.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [  USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.3/input1
[   16.315329] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   16.317297] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   16.811795] input: HP HD Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-7/2-7:1.0/input/input17
[   16.811890] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
me@me-HP430:~$

As you can see, in the OK session something happens around 4.00 that doens't happen when the problem occurs. In these case, the ouptut begins to differ at around 16.00, followed by a series of warnings and error messages. 
Any idea?